# Windows 8 app tile periodically update when it's not running

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, live-tile

I've a app called 'drumtime' installed on Windows 8. It's tile is being changed/updated on every about 10 seconds. This couldn't be done with Background tasks I guess because a background task needs 15 minutes to be executed. But even if the app is not running, it's tile is still being updated.

[image]  after 10 seconds =>  [image]

So, how can I update an app's tile on every 10 seconds even when the app itself is not running?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded Drumtime to check this out, and it is using a peek animation on its live tile.  Check out the [list of available tile templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761491.aspx).  Some of these are "peek" templates which animate smoothly between two different tile templates.  That is what Drumtime is doing.  I used a peek animation in the tile of an app of mine; I wrote [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/20/real-world-live-tiles-working-with-live-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx) with details.

Comment: Thanks Jennifer. Do I need to use background tasks for this 'tile template approach' ?

Comment: No, you don't need to use background tasks with this approach.  If you choose one of the peek templates, it will animate for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff) of updating tile in every minute. You can learn the logic. You have to set schedule in such manner the tile gets update in 10 seconds.